# Blank Characters in Stored Procedure Arguments

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure that takes two arguments that are both strings. The strings may include one or more blank spaces. For instance:

```
exec usp_arch_ptask_assign_me System Administration , Workflow Process Manager
```

or

```
exec usp_arch_ptask_assign_me 'System Administration' , 'Workflow Process Manager'
```

or

```
exec usp_arch_ptask_assign_me [System Administration] , [Workflow Process Manager]
```

The first attempt returns a syntax error and the 2nd and 3rd attempt cause the stored procedure to think that the enclosing characters are part of the actual parameter value.

Suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: The second form is correct. If its failing please add the exact error message and procedure declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
USE DATABASE_NAME;
GO
EXEC usp_arch_ptask_assign_me 'System Administration', 'Workflow Process Manager';
GO
```